# MVC HandleError - Getting the Exception Details

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I have an MVC 4 project where I've implemented the HandleError attribute to get it showing my own custom error page when any exception occurs.

Here is my Error controller:

```
Public Class ErrorController
    Inherits BaseController

    Function Index() As ActionResult
        Return View()
    End Function
End Class
```

However, I can't figure out how to get access to the exception message and stack trace either the controller or the view. I've read that it can be accessed through the model, but how do you access the model?

Answer (score 3):

The error should be of type System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo

The view could look like this:

```
@model HandleErrorInfo
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "Error";
}
<section id="error-page">
    <div>
        <h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>
        <div class="alert alert-error">
            An unexpected Error has occured.<br />
        </div>
    </div>
    @if (Model != null && HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled)
    {
        <div>
            <p>
                <b>Exception:</b> @Model.Exception.Message<br />
                <b>Controller:</b> @Model.ControllerName<br />
                <b>Action:</b> @Model.ActionName
            </p>
            <div>
                <pre>
                    @Model.Exception.StackTrace
                </pre>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</section>
```

If you're wondering how to get the exception model in both ajax & non-ajax-calls have a look at this blog post:
http://blog.christopheargento.net/2012/06/14/unify-exception-handling-between-ajax-and-non-ajax-requests-in-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: What is that first line of code in VB?
@model HandleErrorInfo

Comment: I don't know VB much at all. But in a aspx it would be something like <%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo>" %>

Comment: @ModelType System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason Model is Nothing. Any idea why that would be?

Comment: I did try /Shared/Error.vbhtml, but I have the same problem there. The model is Nothing. After toying around with this for hours I gave up and decided that I'd just store the exception in a shared variable, which I set in the OnException routine in the BaseController.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `ModelType` in your Error view (would be `@model` in C# Razor):

```
@ModelType HandleErrorInfo
```

Comment: Do you know how to key this in VB.NET razor?

Comment: @JeffStock This is VB.NET (the `ModelType`).